# Block UI thread until my call is done, then resume

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.ios, async-await

I'm doing a Xamarin.iOS app.

I want to grab customer/shopping data from my API before my app loads (preload data), rather than call it when the user is using the app. I figured I'd need to hang things in AppDelegate so I can keep it stuck on the splash screen until my API call completes. Assume the user is logged in when the app starts.

My async method that I was calling asynchronously from other parts of the app is:

```
public async Task<CustomerShoppingSummary> GetCustomerShoppingSummary()
```

But that was me calling it during ViewDidLoad or in other areas. I now want to get all this info before the app even starts. So I accidentally figured out I either hang the whole app permanently (using .result, haven't figured out how to make it stop when done) or have it run asynchronously, but no luck achieving the desired behavior of temporarily running things synchronously until the logic is completed.

Where/what method would you recommend I do this in AppDelegate?

Maybe

```
public override void OnActivated(UIApplication application)
```

Any recommendations to run this synchronously and block the UI thread until complete?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't block your UI thread. It's not often in programming you can say "that's *never* a good idea", but hey -- never say never.

Comment: I want to load my data before the app starts - Otherwise they come to the screen and their data isn't there.

Comment: They should see a live, responsive UI, even if there's no data in it yet. If your app hangs on startup, that's a much worse user experience than coming up empty with a spinner. They're waiting just as long either way, but with your idea, it's more annoying. Users hate applications that hang.

Comment: Just show loading indicator while data loads. Blocking UI is bad idea (and IOS might kill your app).

Comment: ok thanks. Maybe i'll do that then

Comment: You are wanting to  run another thread, but block the UI thread while you are running the other thread? I don't recommend it, but why the need to start another thread?  Call from your UI thread.  It will block, believe me.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a spinner on the homepage, just because it looked better after all.

Thanks so much everyone :)

Comment: Just so you know. Something is usually done is create an extended splash screen which is an UIViewController  that looks exactly the same as the splash screen. Here you can do all your service and data initialization then when finished you move to your home screen. This is good because there you can make sure everything is ready and if something happens from there you move to an error page.

Sorry for the long comment.